# Opening web URL with NSButton - Mac OS

Tags: objective-c

### I need some help  with specific copy and paste code to help me get this running.  I want users to click on a NSButton and it will launch safari or their default web browser.

I added a NSButton on my form and then added the declaration and implementation for that but still isn't working.  why is it not working?  Thanks in Advance...

```
 --------.h file--------
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Company. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "HttpRequest.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import "ChimpKit.h"
#define IS_REGISTERED @"IS_REGISTERED"
#define NORMAL_0 0
#define MAILCHIMP_1 1

@protocol RegistrationWindowDelegate

-(void) registrationDidFinished;

@end

@interface RegistrationWindowController : NSWindowController<HttpRequestDelegate,ChimpKitDelegate,NSWindowDelegate> {


    IBOutlet NSButton *pushApp1; //Newly added NSButton for opening Web URL

    IBOutlet NSWindow *registerWindow;
    IBOutlet NSWindow *privacyWindow;
    IBOutlet NSTextField *firstNameField, *lastNameField, *emailField, *verfilyEmailField;
    IBOutlet NSPopUpButton *countryPopUpBtn;
    IBOutlet NSButton *updateCheckBox, *promotionCheckBox;
    IBOutlet NSMenuItem *registerMenuItem;
    IBOutlet NSProgressIndicator *progressIndicator;
    IBOutlet NSButton *registerSoftware,*registerLater;
    id<RegistrationWindowDelegate> delegate;

}
@property(nonatomic,assign) id<RegistrationWindowDelegate> delegate;
- (id)initForRegistrationServer:(int) registrationServer withDelegate:(id<RegistrationWindowDelegate>) delegate;
+ (BOOL) isRegistered;
- (void) setRegistered:(BOOL)state;
- (void) openWindow:(id) sender;
- (BOOL)isValidEmail:(NSString *)email;
-(void) registerWithNormal;
- (void) registerWithMailChimpForApps;
- (NSArray *)addCountries;

@end
```

and this is my .m file (I tried with snippets of code I found on the web)

```
--------.m file--------

//  Copyright (c) 2013 Computer. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RegistrationWindowController.h"

@interface RegistrationWindowController ()

@end

int registrationServer;

@implementation RegistrationWindowController
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)pushApp1:(id)sender {

///Found this snippet on the web, but doesnt work
   NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];
   [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:myURL];


  ///// Also Found this snippet on the web, but doesnt work
  // NSString *s = [ NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
  // [[NSApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:s]];



    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This should work:

```
-(IBAction)pushApp1:(id)sender {
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com"]];
}
```

Comment: If Safari is not the default browser, for instance Chrome is default, then Chrome will be launched to open the url.  How to set specify Safari as the launcher in this case ? thanks

Comment: If Chrome is default, that one should be used.

Answer (score 8):

Code for **Swift 3**

```
@IBAction func pushApp1(_ sender: Any) {
    NSWorkspace.shared().open(URL(string: "http://stackoverflow.com")!)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

swift 5:

```
@IBAction func gotoSite(_ sender: Any) {

    if let url = URL(string: OFFICIAL_SITE_URL) {
        NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
    }

}
```